# LDAP NTLM interop

Tags: ldap, ntlm

Our company uses NTLM to authenticate users.

But there are a bunch of softwares with LDAP authentication support. So, is there a way to setup an LDAP server (preferably under WinNT), which can authenticate users via NTLM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Directory provides an LDAP service.

Comment: He does say WinNT, so maybe he's a decade behind the state of the art and AD isn't available in his environment.

Comment: He does say "preferably" so that doesn't rules out AD. AD can authenticate in both LDAP and NTLM so seems still a valid answer to me.

Comment: Since he doesn't seem to know that AD includes LDAP, I don't want to assume anything at all :-)

Comment: Precisely, that was worth pointing out AD does include LDAP and so might be what the OP is looking for.